# The Scope of a variable initialized in a constructor

Tags: java

If you create a class, say

```
public class Supplier {
    String s;

    public Supplier() {
        s = "MyString";
    }
}
```

Now if you try to access s within a method in the same class. When you run the code, the variable s, still remains null.

Id like to know how the constructor affects a variable.

Comment: Unreproducible. This code should work.

Comment: "if you try to access s within a method in the same class. When you run the code, the variable s, still remains null." it works fine for me. Please add this method in your code example.

Comment: An incredibly common error is to forget to use the "this" keyword when initializing an instance field to the value of a parameter with the same name that is passed into the constructor, but your example code doesn't have this problem.

Comment: To add more informations to your question like proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) use [edit] option.

Comment: Edit: Changed title from "The Scope of a variable declared in a constructor" to "The Scope of a variable initialized in a constructor". I was looking for the former, but this ain't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, this behavior can't really happen. There are a few ways the variable could still be null:

1) You're calling the method in question *before* the variable is set. For example, consider this class and method:

```
public class MyClass{

    private String string;

    public MyClass(){
        method();
        string = "Hello";
    }

    public void method(){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Constructing an object with `MyClass m = new MyClass();` will print `null`, because at the time that `method()` is called, `string` has not yet been set.

2) You're calling the wrong constructor.

```
public class MyClass{

    private String string;

    public MyClass(){
        method();
    }

    public MyClass(String s){
        string = s;
        method();
    }

    public void method(){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Constructing an object with `MyClass m = new MyClass();` will print `null`, because at the time that `method()` is called, `string` has not been set because we called the wrong constructor. Constructing with `MyClass m = new MyClass("Hello");` will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You hit the nail right on the head. God bless.